# How can I access shared Directories on Mac from iPad

Tags: macos, ipad, file-sharing

I have an iPad running iPadOS 16.4 and a MacMini M2 running 13.2.1

On the Mac I have shared a number of folders (including Documents)

On the iPad Files shows a list of shared Directories (including Documents & my home directory)

If I select my home it shows the subdirectories and the files in home.
I can access those files directly in my home (usually simple text files) but while I can see the subdirectories I cannot access content - it says "Content Unavailable".
If I try to access any of the explicitly shared directories it also says "Content Unavailable".

My question is can I access shared Directories and if so how?

---

I am connected via my local network using SMB

Comment: What content are you trying to access?  Is there an App installed on your iPad that is capable of opening that type of file?

Answer (score -1):

I think Apple's official answer is that you need a cable. If you want to share the files easily, I would recommend some form of cloud storage, I've used dropbox, one drive, amazon and apply storage successfully to share files to my iPad.  Good luck.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210598

Comment: The Files  app allows you to connect to different servers like SMB and even FTP without a cable https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/connect-external-devices-or-servers-iph8d8f0f1a0/ios